# cross-env NODE_ENV=development npm run webpack-development

Tags: reactjs, typescript

> il-17g5-app@0.0.1 start /Users/ssurisettii/Documents/il-17g5-app
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development npm run webpack-development

sh: cross-env: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! il-17g5-app@0.0.1 start: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development npm run webpack-development`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the il-17g5-app@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ssurisettii/.npm/_logs/2020-08-25T07_43_41_632Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

1.remove node_moudles
2.remove packagelock.json
3.install npm